# Video effects in JMF

Tags: java, video-processing, jmf

I've managed to create a makeshift video player in Java using JMF. The source code is given below. I want to attach video effects to it, such as converting each frame to greyscale and adding text captions to each frame, using JMF.

Information on video effects with JMF seems to be surprisingly scarce. How would I go about creating filters (or codecs, or whatever they're called) to do the aforementioned tasks?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.media.*;
import javax.media.format.*;
import javax.media.protocol.*;
import javax.media.control.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.io.*;


public class MediaPlayer extends JFrame
{
    public MediaPlayer()
    {

    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        try {
            URL mediaURL = new File("video.avi").toURI().toURL();
            Player mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(mediaURL);
            Component video = mediaPlayer.getVisualComponent();
            Component controls = mediaPlayer.getControlPanelComponent();
            frame.add(video,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.add(controls,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());

        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        catch (NoPlayerException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        catch (CannotRealizeException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hi this is my first post in any forum so sorry for mistakes.

to attach any video effect you need to use a "processor"

here is a code sample to adding a processor and adding effect to it :

```
String strDevName = "your Media MRL";
        CaptureDeviceInfo devInfo = CaptureDeviceManager.getDevice(strDevName);
        MediaLocator ml = devInfo.getLocator();
        DataSource ds;
        Processor p;
        try{
            ds = Manager.createDataSource( ml);  
            p = Manager.createProcessor(ds);
            p.configure();
            while(p.getState() != p.Configured);
            p.setContentDescriptor(null);
            TrackControl[] controls = p.getTrackControls();
            controls[0].setFormat(new VideoFormat( VideoFormat.YUV ));//Specify the Video format of the video specified  in the MRL
               Codec codec[]= { new comp311.jmf.effect.GreyEffect() };//class GrayEffect is a implementation of javax.media.Effect (the link for the class given below) 
            controls[0].setCodecChain(codec);
            p.realize();
            while(p.getState() != p.Realized);
            p.prefetch();
            while(p.getState() != p.Prefetched); 
            video = p.getVisualComponent();
            if ( video != null ) {System.out.println("Prefetched2");
                 pnlVideo.add( video, BorderLayout.CENTER );//pnlVideo is a JPanel
                 p.start();

             }
        }catch(Exception e){}
```

---

[the link for the effect class :](http://turing.une.edu.au/~comp311/Tutorials/Week09/GreyEffect.java)

---

re :

```
while(p.getState() != p.Configured);
while(p.getState() != p.Realized);
while(p.getState() != p.Prefetched);
```

in this places of my program i stopped forowred execution until the processor achives a state , but if the state is not achivable then the prigram gos into a infinity loop. JMF gives a StaeHelper class to overcome the problem google for it.

---